# Tracking down ANTLR errors within a file of many rules?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm about to migrate this [PHP EBNF](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) to ANTLR v4 format.

Unfortunately, ANTLR breaks with the message `can't find rule grammarSpec or tree structure error`:

```
can't find rule grammarSpec or tree structure error: 
(COMBINED_GRAMMAR Php (RULES (RULE start (BLOCK (ALT (top_statement_list 0)))) 
(RULE top_statement_list int _p (BLOCK (ALT (BLOCK (ALT {})) (* (BLOCK (ALT {2 >= 
...

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visit(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:206)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visitGrammar(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:200)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolCollector.process(SymbolCollector.java:76)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java:103)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:399)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolCollector.discoverOuterAlt(SymbolCollector.java:111)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.outerAlternative(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:2284)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.ruleBlock(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:2197)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.rule(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:1663)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.rules(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:1241)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.grammarSpec(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:480)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.LeftRecursiveRule.getAltLabels(LeftRecursiveRule.java:91)
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.Rule.hasAltSpecificContexts(Rule.java:200)
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.LeftRecursiveRule.hasAltSpecificContexts(LeftRecursiveRule.java:60)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.checkForLabelConflicts(SymbolChecks.java:150)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.process(SymbolChecks.java:98)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java:107)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:399)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

If I **reduce the number of rules**, the problem doesn't appear, but ANTLR complains about missing symbols.

**Could anybody provide hints how to track down the error?** Don't see a alternative to reduce the rule count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following is occurring in your grammar (which is not included in the question):

1. It contains a syntax error which the ANTLR 4 grammar compiler is not able to recover from.
2. You found a bug in the ANTLR 4 grammar compiler, which should be reported to the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues).

Comment: Actually, the grammar contained a recursive rule. As soon as I removed the recursion, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @SteAp Some cases of recursion would result in an exception in ANTLR 4.0. Those should be fixed in ANTLR 4.1. If you are using ANTLR 4.1 and getting an exception instead of a clear error message due to recursion in the grammar, you should report a bug.

Comment: That's what I expected. No, I'm with 4.0 But probably will verify the problem with 4.1.

Comment: Ah, just found out, that I'm use 4.1. Should I better use 4.0?